# G. Classroom Format Off

Tags: google-classroom

I have 14 students working in Google Classroom.
One student is having this issue.
When he "Creates" a document through the Google Classroom assignment stream, the document formatting is tiny and spaced weird.
He has to make his font 18pt to make it even out to the required 12pt font and I just have to overlook the spacing error (assignments should be double spaced but his are more like 3.7 spaced).

He is using IE and I asked him to try Chrome but has the same problem.
He is the only student out of 14 having this issue, using the same Classroom.

Comment: Screen resolution? Zoom level in browser? Document defaults incorrectly set?

Comment: Those are all correct, @ale. Thanks for trying!